# Is there benefit in multiple levels of clustering?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I'm currently developing a clustering model and seeking something a bit novel.

I have looked at initial clustering to 5 clusters and then applying another run to cluster these into 2 each (so 10 total).

Results are similar but definitely not the same as if I ran just once for 10 clusters, rather than 5 and then 2.

Is there any obvious difference or benefit / drawback to such an approach? I cannot find much academia on this and potentially with good reason.

Comment: Clustering is a very domain-specific task with no general definition of what is a "good" clustering. It all depends on your needs, but unfortunately you don't describe what you need. Note that hierarchical clustering algorithms exist; personally I have good experiences with HDBSCAN on my particular problems.

Answer (score 0):

Think about generalizing your approach by searching for optimal numbers of clusters in both steps (combined) to minimize the number of clusters while maximizing your coverage. This is an objective where your method benefits.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).